# Why does my bounce animation start 50px above where it should start?

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation

I've attempted to create a bounce affect with text

https://codepen.io/rybohi/pen/YzydGPo
Here is where i think the bug is

```
@keyframes jump{

  0%, 40%{
    transform:scale(2,.5) translate(0,100px);
  }

  45%,55%{
    transform:translate(0,-50px);
  }

  55%, 100%{
    transform:translate(0,0);
  }
}
```

but for some reason i have a bug
the bounce affect starts 50px above where it should start
any help ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure to understand what you are trying to achieve, but here's something that might help :

```
  0%, 40%{
    /* Replace 100px with 200px */
    transform:scale(2,.5) translate(0,200px);
  }
```

The letters will be "crushed" instantly, but they will stay roughly at the same position they were.

It looks like the `translate` function is affected by the scale used.

Answer (score 0):

It's because of the scaling you're applying at the start of your animation:

```
 0%, 40%{
    transform:scale(2,.5) translate(0,100px);
 }
```

You've started with the letters translated (in your `.test` class), so when you scale the letters it scales the translation too.

If you remove the scaling you'll see there is no 50px jump at the start.